# Why does the input value my reply function only work in one specific tweet?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, rendering

So I am working on a twitter project at the moment and as a stretch goal, I am doing a reply function. The reply itself is being rendered properly into each tweets, but the value of the reply input field only gets passed into one of the tweets and the other receive a blank reply regardless of the content of the input field.

This is my event listener:

```
// Identify which icon was clicked
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){

  if(e.target.dataset.like){
    console.log(e.target.dataset)
    handleLikeClick(e.target.dataset.like)
    
  }

  else if(e.target.dataset.retweet){
    console.log(e.target.dataset)
    handleRetweetClick(e.target.dataset.retweet)
  }

  else if(e.target.dataset.reply){
    console.log(e.target.dataset)
    handleReplyClick(e.target.dataset.reply)
  }

  else if(e.target.id === "tweet-btn"){
    handleTweetBtnClick()
  }

  else if(e.target.id === "post-btn"){
    
    handlePostBtnClick(e.target.dataset.post)
    
  }

  
})
```

This is my reply function:

```
//post a reply
function handlePostBtnClick(tweetId){
  let postValue = document.getElementById("reply-input").value
  console.log(postValue)
  const targetTweetObj = tweetsData.filter(function(tweet){
       return tweet.uuid === tweetId
  })[0]

  console.log(targetTweetObj)


  targetTweetObj.replies.unshift(
    {
      handle: "@Scrimba",
      profilePic: "images/scrimbalogo.png",
      tweetText: `${postValue}`
    } 
  )
  
  render()
  
}
```

And this is a part of the function that renders the replies and the reply box to the html:

```
  // renders the replies to tweets
    if(tweet.replies.length > 0){
      tweet.replies.forEach(function(reply){
        repliesHtml += `
        <div class="tweet-reply">
          <div class="tweet-inner">
          <img src="${reply.profilePic}" class="profile-pic">
              <div>
                  <p class="handle">${reply.handle}</p>
                  <p class="tweet-text">${reply.tweetText}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       `
      })
    }


      repliesHtml += `
      <div class="tweet-input-area">
        <img src="images/scrimbalogo.png" class="profile-pic">
        <textarea id="reply-input" placeholder="Write a reply"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button id="post-btn" data-post="${tweet.uuid}">Post</button>
      `
```

Comment: This is a good opportunity to start [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  Could you update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: not sure if it's an error in your question or your code, but in your question you say, that `handlePostBtnClick` is the function that handles your reply, but in the code I also see a `handleReplyClick`... maybe that's already the issue? if not, please do as @David said

Comment: IDs should be unique. You shouldn't use `id="reply-input"` and `id="post-btn"` in every reply. Use classes instead.